# Detecting if struct exists for key in map

Tags: dictionary, go

According to the Golang documentation on maps,

> If the requested key doesn't exist, we get the value type's zero value. In this case the value type is int, so the zero value is 0:
>
> ```
> j := m["root"] // j == 0
> ```

So I'm trying to determine if a struct exists with a given string, how would I determine this? Would I just check for an empty struct with zerod values? What would the comparison here look like?

```
type Hello struct{}
structMap := map[string]Hello{}
j := structMap["example"]
if(j==?) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the special "comma, ok" form which tells if the key was found in the map. Go [Spec: Index Expressions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)

> An index expression on a map `a` of type `map[K]V` used in an assignment or initialization of the special form
>
> ```
> v, ok = a[x]
> v, ok := a[x]
> var v, ok = a[x]
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of `ok` is `true` if the key `x` is present in the map, and `false` otherwise.

So in your code:

```
type Hello struct{}
structMap := map[string]Hello{}
if j, ok := structMap["example"]; !ok {
    // "example" is not in the map
}
```